# How can I design a realistic landscape?

Tags: geology, landscaping

Designing landscapes is difficult, because we often don't take into account the geological processes that formed them in the first place. You wouldn't have a ten-mile-high mountain on Earth, because the tectonic plates never produced enough force in their interactions to create such a large mass of rock. Neither would you really have a river with massive waterfalls every mile until it reaches the sea, because the likelihood is that the land would flatten long before it reached the sea and more waterfalls would just take it underground.

So, taking into account the geology of landscapes, how can I go about designing a *realistic* landscape? I'm looking for things like

- dimensions
- relative locations
- features

along with reasoning of *why* these things would be the way they are.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the [Cartography Guild](http://www.cartographersguild.com/content.php).  I've poked around their forums on rare occasion, so I'm pretty sure they've got some tutorials in this regard, but it has been a while since I was last there.  They do monthly contests as well, which are always neat to look at.  Different folks have different methods.

Comment: This is very planet-specific (Olympus Mons on Mars _is_ over 10 miles high.) You did mention Earth in your second sentence but I'm just clarifying since that affects the answer.

Comment: As The Anathama pointed out, it is very possible to get very high mountains without plate tectonics. Olympus Mons is of course an extinct volcano, so you're going to have different forces at work there. In that case, one of the contributing factors was the lower gravity of Mars allowed it to grow higher than would have been possible on Earth.

Comment: Is your question already covered by the [similar questions in this series](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2595/3202)?

Comment: @Samuel To some extend the landmass formation works for it, but it doesn't go into enough specifics for me. I'm looking at typical and reasoned detail, rather than the broad scope.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Ok, the landmass question is the bones of landscape formation, the details might be covered in the other questions, like erosion, coastlines, waterways, etc. I'm just looking for an answer that doesn't simply list those answers.

Comment: @Artofcode Are you interested in the IT/GameDev view on it? I'm going to prepare an answer, but it may take some while because I have to research a bit. (Reasong for *why* will be included)

Comment: @J_F_B_M Sounds interesting, go for it :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the link Samuel linked covers all the aspects required to create a realistic landscape - if you follow all the tutorials in the answers, you'll be able to create said realistic yet never-before seen landscapes. Afterall, the series does include biomes, erosion, landmass, coastlines, waterways, and even underwater geography... Disclaimer: I created a world using those tutorials, and I think it looks quite nice :)

Comment: For reference: [My draft](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4cxnl3q9lsn30v9/SE_Draft_How%20can%20I%20design%20a%20realistic%20landscape.txt?dl=0), a [source](http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html), search also after perlin noise, [this other source](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/), [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/cesium/Public/terrain.pdf) (it covers erosion, important to generate realistic mountains and rivers) and look into wind-shadow of mountains, which I don't have a link for (yet).

Comment: Also look into an [Excel-File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsha70zubevs61y/Midpoint_Adjustment.xlsx?dl=0) I made for Midpoint-Adjustment (sorry for the double-post, char-limit).

Comment: This should go more specific, e.g. "How many waterfalls can I realistically fit into a thousand mile river?"  As is, it just seems to replace the canonical series of questions, which makes it incredibly broad.  What specific problem are you facing?  That seems more answerable.